# Python index error when trying to use list.insert

Tags: python, insert, indexing, range

Here is a section (a large section) of my code.  http://pastebin.com/KCZNkYNB

What i have happening, by design, is to iterate through this sequence until the distance that i am calculating is minimized by 1cm.  I don't want to move on to my next epoch until that, which is why i thought i should use .insert for my lists.  I need to overwrite the data at the indices it's currently at.

The error i am getting is:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "receiver2.py", line 342, in <module>
    main()
  File "receiver2.py", line 244, in main
    N.insert(k, ( dec.sqrt( (dec(satellite_output.x[k]) - dec(x_veh_coords[epoch]))**2 + (dec(satellite_output.y[k]) - d
ec(y_veh_coords[epoch]))**2 + (dec(satellite_output.z[k]) - dec(z_veh_coords[epoch]))**2 ) ) )
IndexError: list index out of range
```

---

This error corresponds with line number 54 in the pastebin file.

What I don't understand is how an index is out of range when you're insert.
Full pastebin output:  http://pastebin.com/qKhRjn2Q
You will see at the bottom of that output that the last "k" indice was 7, then it reached epoch 1, and incremented to indice 8 but then crapped out with the index out of range.  I'm extremely confused as to why that happens.  I assure you all the data does exists that is trying to be inserted as if i were to commend out the .insert portion and uncomment the .append, it works fine.  Unfortunately, i just realized that append is "hiding" the data i need in order to compute my jacobian correctly.

I hope i've given enough information.  Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Suppose k is it out or range? Try splitting up to code in several lines. This is more a question about how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have six index operations in the error line (e.g. `satellite_output.x[k]`); one of those is probably causing the fault, not the insert operation.

The error message is less helpful than it might be.

Comment: Indeed you should check all the arrays you are using, my bet the out of range exception is on them.

Comment: On line 49 is an .append that contains the same calculation using the same indices.  Commenting out line 54 and uncommenting line 49 does not give me any indexerrors.

I could show some debugging output that data does indeed exist in my satellite_output.x if you would like.

Comment: I got it figured out.  :D

What i needed to do was make sure that when my distance was minimized to the accuracy i was looking for, i needed to set my x,y,z vech coords to use that new approximated cartesian coordinate for the next epoch.

I appreciate all the responses, sorry to have wasted a bit of your time for something so trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I got it figured out.  :D

What i needed to do was make sure that when my distance was minimized to the accuracy i was looking for, i needed to set my x,y,z vech coords to use that new approximated cartesian coordinate for the next epoch.

I appreciate all the responses, sorry to have wasted a bit of your time for something so trivial.